# Splitting F# module in multiple parts in the same file

Tags: f#

I have the following working F# source file

```
namespace Namspa1

[<AutoOpen>]
module M1 = 
    let [<Literal>] constant1 = "Hello, "

type Greeter(name) = 
    member x.Greet() = sprintf "%s%s" constant1 name

module M2 =
    let greet name = Greeter(name).Greet()
```

This works but what I want is define the function greet in the same module M1 where constant1 is defined. 
In other words, using only one file I want to obtain

```
Namspa1.M1.constant1
Namspa1.Greeter
Namspa1.M1.greet //not Namspa1.M2.greet
```

- constant1 is a value, so must be inside a module
- Greater uses constant1 so must be later in the file; I want it to be in the namespace, not inside a module, so it is non indented
- Finally greet is a function, so it must be in a module and I want to use the same module M1. It also uses Greeter, so it must be located after the type definition.

If I try to change the greet function definition as

```
module M1 =
    let greet name = Greeter(name).Greet()
```

I get an Duplicate definition error for M1.

How do I do it?

**EDIT**

It's been suggested that using attribute CompilationRepresentation(CompilationRepresentationFlags.ModuleSuffix) fixes the Duplicate definition error, which is true so thanks for this.

However my request is about extending M1. I want to be able to use M1.greet as if the function was defined in M1.
For example, if I try to use the definitions externally (e.g. another source file), I can use M2.greet, so I want to use M1.greet, which is not possible with the attribute

Comment: I'd refactor `Greeter` so it takes that constant value in its constructor. Why couple its behavior to a compile-time constant in a module? Why not just inline that constant?

Comment: @Taylor Wood there are many ways to refactor it, but I want to know whether it is possible to do what I ask or it is a limit of the compiler or the language. Moreover, M1 could contain many elements and not only one constant, this is a simple ad hoc example to make clear and concise my question

Comment: With the ModuleSuffix compilation representation, M1.greet is accessible as such from other F# source files. A recursive namespace is a better solution though.

Comment: @cadull I am using VS 2017 and from a different file I can only access M1.constant1, M1.greet is accessible only in the same file. If I use my original source, instead, M2.greet is accessible also from different files

Comment: Indeed. I've updated my answer with a workaround, but using the feature for this purpose appears to be unsupported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to achieve is possible by using a [recursive namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/namespaces#recursive-namespaces). Notice the `rec` keyword when declaring the namespace.

```
namespace rec Namspa1

[<AutoOpen>]
module M1 =
    let [<Literal>] constant1 = "Hello, "
    let greet name = Greeter(name).Greet()

type Greeter(name) =
    member x.Greet() = sprintf "%s%s" constant1 name
```

Answer (score 4):

This is possible by setting the `CompilationRepresentation` attribute to [`CompilationRepresentationFlags.ModuleSuffix`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/core.compilationrepresentationflags-enumeration-%5Bfsharp%5D). Extending a module like this is not an intended use case, so the second module definition needs to be moved to a separate source file.

First file:

```
namespace Namspa1

[<AutoOpen>]
module M1 = 
    let [<Literal>] constant1 = "Hello, "

type Greeter(name) = 
    member x.Greet() = sprintf "%s%s" constant1 name
```

Second file:

```
namespace Namspa1

[<CompilationRepresentation(CompilationRepresentationFlags.ModuleSuffix)>]
module M1 =
    let greet name = Greeter(name).Greet()
```

Technically, it generates a module named M1Module, which will affect access from other .NET languages.